# test if an associative array contains a key in D

Tags: d, associative-array

The question is pretty self-explanatory; I want to be able to check if an associative array contains a value I'm about to (potentially) insert, before I actually insert it. Is there a simple way to do this without searching through `dict.keys`? Maybe something like `if (dict.contains(val)) ...`?

Answer (score 8):

To test if a **key** is in an associative array, use the `in` operator:

```
string[int] aa;

string* ps = 100 in aa;

if(ps)
{
    // 100 is a key in aa, ps is a pointer to the corresponding value
}
else
{
    // 100 is not a key in aa
}
```

To test if a **value** exists, you'll have to search through `aa.values`.

Comment: it's worthy to note that a pointer will evaluate to false in a conditional if and only if the pointer `is null`

Comment: I think the usual way to write that code is `if(auto v = key in aa) { fn(*v); } else { ... }`

Answer (score 1):

```
if (!dict.get(key, null))
     dict[key] = val;
```

Comment: Doesn't work since `null` could be a valid value in `dict`; you could call `dict[key] = null;`, then `key in dict` will return `true`.

Comment: @beeryboy It depends on the situation whether you can use it or not